# Multidimensional associative arrays, combining with PHP

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array, merge, associative-array

Seeing the code below, When status, number, and date are identical in multiple records, I want to combine the record, and combine the different version numbers into one element, in one combined array element, hopefully my example below better explains what I am after.

I am having a tough time coming up with a clean and efficient way to do this.  Anybody able to help me out? I was not able to pinpoint similar questions to this problem.

Lets say I have an array:

```
 array (size=4)
  995 => 
    array (size=4)
      'status' => string 'accept' (length=6)
      'number' => string '130106' (length=6)
      'date' => string 'July 11th, 2013' (length=15)
      'version_number' => 1
  996 => 
    array (size=4)
      'status' => string 'won' (length=3)
      'number' => string '130106' (length=6)
      'date' => string 'July 11th, 2013' (length=15)
      'version_number' => null
  993 => 
    array (size=4)
      'status' => string 'won' (length=3)
      'number' => string '130106' (length=6)
      'date' => string 'July 11th, 2013' (length=15)
      'version_number' => null
  992 => 
    array (size=4)
      'status' => string 'accept' (length=6)
      'number' => string '130106' (length=6)
      'date' => string 'July 11th, 2013' (length=15)
      'version_number' => 3
```

Desired result:

```
array (size=3)
      0 => 
        array (size=4)
          'status' => string 'accept' (length=6)
          'number' => string '130106' (length=6)
          'date' => string 'July 11th, 2013' (length=15)
          'version_number' => array (1, 3)
      1 => 
        array (size=4)
          'status' => string 'won' (length=3)
          'number' => string '130106' (length=6)
          'date' => string 'July 11th, 2013' (length=15)
          'version_number' => null
      2 => 
        array (size=4)
          'status' => string 'won' (length=3)
          'number' => string '130106' (length=6)
          'date' => string 'July 11th, 2013' (length=15)
          'version_number' => null
```

Comment: "I am having a tough time coming up with a clean and efficient way to do this." That implies that you have tried something.  Can you show us your attempt(s)?

Comment: Essentially a hodgepodge of array duplication, for eachs, and manually bulding the new array. I just felt like theres gotta be a better way with some php array sorting functions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be able to use the following function:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-assoc.php

Loop through your array and check the intersection of each index of the array. If status, number, and date all intersect, then combine versions and assign back to the index you are checking against and pop what it was compared to.  Once you complete checks against all of the other indices, then take your current index and push it into a fresh array.

I'll lay down some pseudo code for you since I don't have a server to access at the moment to test, simply loop through your array elements and the compare should work like this:

```
array_intersect_assoc($array[995],$array[996]); -> intersect = number, date
array_intersect_assoc($array[995],$array[993]); -> intersect = number, date
array_intersect_assoc($array[995],$array[992]); -> intersect = status, number, date OK

array_push($array[995]['version'], $array[992]['version']);
unset($array[992]);

end of loop,
array_push($new_array, $array[995]);

$new_array: 0 => 
               'status' => string 'accept'
               'number' => string '130106' 
               'date' => string 'July 11th, 2013'
               'version_number' => array (1, 3)

#now loop moves on to the rest of the remaining elements.
```

So, it will go through your loop accumulating all of the versions into one index, removing all of the redundant data further in the array (so we don't loop over it again), then upon a full iteration, saves the index to a new array.